# how can i cut one line on two on a cat /ect/passwd?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I'm trying to write a command that shows all odd lines of 
`/etc/passwd`:

I've tried:

```
sh-3.2$ cat /etc/passwd | grep -vn \# | sed '0~2d'
```

but it didn't work

```
sed: 1: "0~2d": invalid command code ~
```

Is there a different  way to obtain the result?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. YMMV if you rely on us reading a command that doesn't do what you want to figure out what it is you do want.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Do you want to delete the first 2 or 3 lines of the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step syntax is a [GNU extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). 
`sed 'n;d'` should be the portable version of your `sed` invocation.

Comment: I suggest you update your answer to include the actual command for this answer to be recognized. ie. `cat /etc/passwd | grep -vn \# | sed 'n;d'`